# How do I update TextView using 2 seperate spinner not independent of each other?

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner

In this app, each spinner is used to make an API call.
Now, spinner 1 is for the coin(crypto) and 2 is for currency(USD, YEN etc) in which coin is to be displayed. The spinner 1 works perfectly fine! But spinner 2 wont update the TextView.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPriceTextView = findViewById(R.id.priceLabel);
    Spinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.currency_spinner);
    Spinner spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.coin_spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the String array and a spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.currency_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.coin_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    // TODO: Set an OnItemSelected listener on the spinner
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Bitcoin-Ticker", "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spinner has been set with listener " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Bitcoin-Ticker", "Final url1 is: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            finalUrl1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            update();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            Log.d("Bitcoin-Ticker", "No item selected.");
        }
    });
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Bitcoin-Ticker", "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spinner has been set with listener" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Bitcoin-Ticker", "Spinner choice is: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            String spinItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            finalUrl2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            if (spinItem.equals("BTC")) {
                finalUrl2 = BASE_URL1 + finalUrl1;

            } else {
                finalUrl2 = BASE_URL2 + finalUrl1;

            }
            Log.d("Bitcoin-Ticker", "Final url2 is: " + finalUrl2);
            update();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! so your problem is in update()? what would you like to do there?

Comment: We're gonna need to see that update() method.